Verifying Lipschitz Condition for a Function Involving Trigonometric and Rational Terms
I have this ode: $$v''(r)+\frac{1}{2}(v'(r))^2+P(r)v'(r)=Q(r),$$
where $$P(r)=− \frac{k^3r + 12\pi \rho_0 kr \cos(kr) + 4\pi\rho_0(k^2r^2 − 3)\sin(kr)}
{r[k^3r − 8\pi\rho_0[\sin(kr) − kr\cos(kr)]},$$
$$Q(r)= \frac{8\pi\rho_0kr(r^2 + 5) \cos(kr) + 8\pi\rho_0(k^2r^3 + k^2r^2 − r − 5) \sin(kr)}
{k^3r^3 − 8\pi\rho_0r^2[\sin(kr) − kr \cos(kr)] }.$$
I wrote the equation as systems of ordinary differential equations:
$$\begin{align}v'(r) &= y(r)\\
y'(r) &= -\frac{1}{2}(y(r))^2 - P(r)y(r) + Q(r)
\end{align}.$$
Then, I defined $w=(v,y)$ and $F(w)=(y, -\frac{1}{2}y^2 - Py + Q)$
I am trying to verify whether the following function $F(w)$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition:
$$F(w) = \left(y, -\frac{1}{2}y^2 + P(r) + Q\right).$$
I want to determine if $F(w)$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition, i.e., if there exists a constant $K>0$  such that:
$$\|F(w_1) - F(w_2)\| \leq K \|w_1 - w_2\|, \quad \text{for all } w_1, w_2.$$
My ideas:

I expanded $\|F(w_1) - F(w_2)\|^2$, which depends on the terms $P(r)$ and $Q(r)$, specifically:

$$\|F(w_1) - F(w_2)\|^2 = (y_1 - y_2)^2 \left(1 + \left(\frac{1}{2}(y_1 + y_2) + P(r)\right)^2\right).$$
Thus, determining whether $F(w)$ is Lipschitz hinges on analyzing whether $P(r)$ is bounded.

Analysis of $P(r)$:

For $r \to \infty $: Both the numerator and denominator of $ P(r) $ grow as $ r^2$, modulated by the oscillatory terms $\sin(kr)$ and $\cos(kr)$. Hence, $ P(r)$ appears to remain bounded for large $ r $.
For $ r \to 0 $: The $ \frac{1}{r} $ term in the denominator suggests that $ P(r) $ might diverge.

Preliminary Conclusion:

$F(w)$ does not seem to be globally Lipschitz because $P(r)$ may diverge as $ r \to 0 $.
$ F(w) $ could be locally Lipschitz if $ r $ is restricted to an interval $ [a, b] $.
My questions:

Is my analysis correct? Am I overlooking any key aspects in evaluating $ P(r) $?
Is there a rigorous way to prove that $ P(r) $ is bounded in some domain?
How can I formally demonstrate whether $ F(w) $ is Lipschitz locally or globally?

Any advice or corrections would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
